# Angular: Transform a request result in a observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I started doing my project in a module by module basis, so each one had to access the user.

Now that I'm polishing it, I'm having multiple API requests for the same thing (user info).

Much I found on the internet is deprecated and doesn't work anymore (mostly RxJs stuff).

What I have: the callback from the API with the user info.
What I want: something shareable globally in the project (I only need one request for the API for the user info)

I'm trying right now to turn an observable into another:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginInfoService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private userURL = `${environment.API}/loginUser`;

  private user$: Observable<LoggedUser>;
  private request = false;

  public retrieveUser(): Observable<LoggedUser> {

    if (!this.request&& !this.user$) {
      console.log("call request");
      this.user$ = this.getUserJson();
    }

    return this.user$;
  }

  private getUserJson() {
    console.log('actual request');
    this.request = true;
    return this.http.get<LoggedUser>(`${this.userURL}?key='123'`);
  }
}
```

I'm using for testing "json-server" and while I get only one 'actual request' printed, the server shows multiple requests there. 
I'm using the latest stable version of Angular.

Comment: Do you need to change `request = true` to `this.request = true`, or is it just a typo in this post? You shouldn't need that additional check because you're covered by `!this.user$`

Comment: typo, fixed there. But I was out of ideas as to why it was calling so many times... and started double checking everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [shareReplay](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/multicasting/sharereplay), the http request will be executed only once then the result will be cached for any new subscription. Also, you can remove the request variable.

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class LoginInfoService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  private userURL = `${environment.API}/loginUser`;

  private user$: Observable<LoggedUser>;

  public retrieveUser(): Observable<LoggedUser> {
    return this.user$.pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }

  private getUserJson() {
    return this.http.get<LoggedUser>(`${this.userURL}?key='123'`);
  }
}
```

Comment: I've changed to make it work like: "private user$: Observable<LoggedUser> = this.getUserJson().pipe(shareReplay(1));" and on retrieveUser just "return this.user$;" thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with two subscriptions but only one request. Solved with ReplaySubject: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/only-one-request

PS: I used a different API so you have to adjust the `userURL`.